# How to assign Composite Roles in KeyCloak

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am using keycloak-admin-client 13.0.0 in my Spring Boot Application. I can get all the roles from KeyCloak. I want one role as composite roles and assigned roles into that role.

I have used the following code to assign composite. But its assigns all roles as composite. I want to assign a particular role as composite

> ```
> public List<RoleRepresentation> addComposites(String roleName) {
>     // list of roles
>     List<RoleRepresentation> roleRepresentations = listRoles();
>     RoleResource roleResource = rolesResource.get(roleName);
>     roleResource.addComposites(roleRepresentations);
>
>     return roleRepresentations;
> }
> ```

[image: roles]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But its assigns all roles as composite. I want to assign a particular
> role as composite

That is because you added the complete list :

```
List<RoleRepresentation> roleRepresentations = listRoles();
...
roleResource.addComposites(roleRepresentations);
```

You need to filter from that list the role that you want to add as composite something as follows:

```
Optional<RoleRepresentation> compositive = 
          roleRepresentations.stream()
                             .filter(r -> r.getName().equals(nameOfRoleToBeAddedAsCompositive))
                             .findFirst();

if(compositive.isPresent())
   roleResource.addComposites(List.of(compositive.get()));
```

Or cleaner:

```
roleRepresentations.stream()
                   .filter(r -> r.getName().equals(nameOfRoleToBeAddedAsCompositive))                                              
                   .findFirst()
                   .ifPresent(role -> roleResource.addComposites(List.of(role)))
```